# Virtual TreeView losing toUseExplorerTheme

Tags: delphi-7, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree, delphi

I have gridlines and toUseExplorerTheme enabled in virtualtreeview (DesignTime).

I would like to remove the gridlines in runtime but it seems like I'm losing the toUseExplorerTheme property. Is this a bug or did I miss something? I tried to add it back to the set/options but no luck. I have also the XP Manifest.

Here's a little bit of code:

```
VirtualStringTree1.TreeOptions.PaintOptions := VirtualStringTree1.TreeOptions.PaintOptions - [toShowVertGridlines]; // I lose the ExplorerTheme :/
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with latest revision. Anyway it might be better to report this to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/issues/list) of the VTV project.

Comment: You're right. The latest revision has this problem fixed. Thank you very much :)